# How to fix a problem in method's variable

Tags: c#

Weird problem in a method that I created.
I cannot return the `pointer` variable.

```
public static int serch_Acount(List<Accounts> AllAccount)
{
    int pointer;   
    Console.WriteLine("please enter the id number");
    int idSerch = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    for (int i = 0; i < AllAccount.Count ; i++)
    {
        if (idSerch ==AllAccount[i].id)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("name: "+AllAccount[i].accountName);
            Console.WriteLine("id: " + AllAccount[i].id);
            Console.WriteLine("age: " + AllAccount[i].age);
            Console.WriteLine("balance: " + AllAccount[i].balance);
            pointer = i;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("id doent found");
            pointer= -1;
        }
    }
    return pointer;
}
```

Use of unassigned local variable `pointer`

Comment: If `AllCount.Count` is 0, then the loop won't be run and pointer won't be assigned.

Comment: and your code logically is wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 : You pointer should be assing a value such as -1 , 0 , default

2 : If you found anything then you must return otherwise next itterator will change your pointer

```
    public static int serch_Acount(List<Accounts> AllAccount)
    {
        int pointer = default; // does not need
        Console.WriteLine("please enter the id number");
        int idSerch = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        for (int i = 0; i < AllAccount.Count; i++)
        {
            if (idSerch == AllAccount[i].id)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("name: " + AllAccount[i].accountName);
                Console.WriteLine("id: " + AllAccount[i].id);
                Console.WriteLine("age: " + AllAccount[i].age);
                Console.WriteLine("balance: " + AllAccount[i].balance);
                pointer = i; // does not need
                return pointer;
                // return i;
            }
            Console.WriteLine("id doent found");
            pointer = -1; // does not need
        }
        return pointer;
        // return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Assigning -1 instead of default is better here because if it doesn't find an element it should be -1, not 0 (ints default).

Answer (score 2):

If `AllAccount` is empty then the loop will never execute, and no value will ever be assigned to `pointer`.

Looking at you code I suspect you can easily fix this by setting it to `-1` when declaring it:

```
int pointer = -1;
```